# Why return value is 0 when use Mergesort in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, sorting, merge, mergesort

I am making merge sort code but it does not sort. Do you see what's wrong with it?

```
def mergeSort(L):
   if len(L) == 1:
       return L
   else:
       # divide
       L1 = mergeSort(L[0:round(len(L)/2)])
       L2 = mergeSort(L[round(len(L)/2):len(L)])
    
       # merge
       i = 0
       j = 0
       K = []
       while i < len(L1) and j < len(L2):
           if L1[i] < L2[j]:
               K.append(L1[i])
               i=i+1
           else:
               K.append(L2[j])
               j=j+1
       return K
```

Input:

```
L = [1,2,5,7,8,0,10,21,32,53,16,16,48,59,64,53,75,52,42,21,98,76‌​]
```

Output:

```
L = [0]
```

Comment: Show the output for a given input.

Comment: Input: L = [1,2,5,7,8,0,10,21,32,53,16,16,48,59,64,53,75,52,42,21,98,76]
Output: L = [0]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
while i < len(L1) and j < len(L2):
```

This doesn't look right to me. With this condition, the loop will end once either of i or j reaches the end of their respective list. There might still be elements in the other list that never get iterated over, as a result.

Try changing that `and` to an `or`, and add some checking to make sure that inter-list comparison only happens when neither list has been completely iterated yet:

```
    while i < len(L1) or j < len(L2):
        if i < len(L1) and (j == len(L2) or L1[i] < L2[j]):
            K.append(L1[i])
            i=i+1
        else:
            K.append(L2[j])
            j=j+1
```

Now your code outputs `[0, 1, 2, 5, 7, 8, 10, 16, 16, 21, 21, 32, 42, 48, 52, 53, 53, 59, 64, 75, 76, 98]`.

Answer (score 3):

Consider this line:

```
while i < len(L1) and j < len(L2):
```

For example, if all the elements in `L1` are smaller than all the elements in `L2` then this loop will put all the elements in `L1` into the result `K`. The loop will then finish and *all of `L2` will be ignored*. You need to mop up the remaining elements when this loop finishes. Add this line of code immediately after the loop:

```
K.extend(L1[i:] + L2[j:])
```

By the way, I found this by stepping through your code with a debugger, with input `L=[2,1]`. I found that when I only went through the `while` loop for one iteration, and since one element is added each loop iteration there could only be one element in the result. If you don't already know how to step through code with a debugger, now would be a good time to learn.

Comment: The nice thing about this approach compared to the other answer is that you don't have to complicate the conditionals within the loop with a lot of boundary checking.

Answer (score 1):

In while condition the "And" operation should have changed to "or" and then your problem is solved.

```py
def merge_sort(L):
    if len(L) == 1:
        return L

    else:
        # divide
        L1 = merge_sort(L[0:round(len(L) / 2)])
        L2 = merge_sort(L[round(len(L) / 2):len(L)])

        # merge
        i = 0
        j = 0
        K = []
        while i < len(L1) or j < len(L2):
            if i < len(L1) and (j == len(L2) or L1[i] < L2[j]):
                K.append(L1[i])
                i = i + 1
            else:
                K.append(L2[j])
                j = j + 1
        return K
```

Now you will get the desired output and it will not show you zero.